# Select statement across a join table

Tags: mysql, select, composite

Have three tables that look like this:

```
PersonTable
Person.ID
Person.Name

PersonTypeCompositeTable
Person.ID
PersonType.ID

PersonTypeTable
PersonType.ID
PersonType.Category
```

For this example, say the values of PersonTypeCompositeTable are:

```
1,A
2,A
3,B
```

How to I write a SELECT statement that will return all the people with a PersonType of "A"?

---

**UPDATE: (Working version of answer posted)**

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PersonTable p
  INNER JOIN PersonTypeCompositeTable ptc
    ON p.ID = ptc.ID
  INNER JOIN PersonTypeTable pt
    ON ptc.ID = pt.ID
WHERE pt.Category = 'A'
```

Comment: I don't think that is a composite table. It is just a joining table

Comment: +1 @Joe Philllips: You're correct, thanks! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) between the three tables.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PersonTable p
  INNER JOIN PersonTypeCompositeTable ptc
    ON p.Person.ID = ptc.Person.ID
  INNER JOIN PersonTypeTable pt
    ON ptc.PersonType.ID = pt.PersonType.ID
WHERE pt.PersonType.Category = 'A'
```

Comment: +1 @Wes: RTFM yourself... :-) ...just kidding, but really, I've know about JOINS forever and still don't get them, use them rarely -- and Oded get super easy rep points. Besides, he ended up updating his answer.

Comment: +1 @Oded: Heading out the door, I'll QA this first thing in the morning when I get in the office and select it as the answer - or post a comment. Thanks!

Comment: @blunders - Joins are something you really need to get your head around if you are working with SQL.

Comment: +1 @Oded: I agree - what do you think of this tutorial: http://geekyisawesome.blogspot.com/2011/03/sql-joins-tutorial.html -- thanks!!

Comment: @blunders - Seems decent enough.

Comment: @Oded: So, checked the code you posted, and posted what to me appears to be the working version. The code to posted appears to create a pointer that points to itself; meaning ALIAS.TABLE.COLUMN doesn't work, but ALIAS.COLUMN does. Again, the working code is posted as an update to the description of my answer. Need to know if I'm missing something. If not, just update your answer, and I'll selected as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @blunders - My assumption was that `PersonType.ID` and such were column names.

Comment: @Oded: Cool, makes sense -- selecting your post as the answers and leaving everything as is. Cheers!